# How to display a newly added Customer attribute in Manage Customer View in Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento

I have got three stores installed on the same installation of Magento Enterprise edition.

I created an extra Customer Attribute and it did get successfully showed up on front-end. But I would like to display this attribute in "Manage Customer View" in admin  so that I can use this attribute to filter my customer records out.

But it doesn't get showed up with the other attributes. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created a custom module which over rides Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php and modified the following functions. Since I wanted to add a column which is a part of my customer's billing information, my code looked like this.

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $collection->joinAttribute('your_column', 'customer_address/your_column', 'default_billing', null, 'left');                   
    parent::setCollection($collection);
}

$this->addColumn('Company', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your column'),
        'index'     => 'your_column',
        'type'      => 'text',
        //'renderer' => 'ConstantMedia_Adminhtml_Block_Render_Confirmation',

    ));
```

You can tweak the code according to your requirements. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to extend:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
```

located in:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
```

and add your column in `_prepareColumns()`

Comment: But I am using Magento Enterprise. And I an see that attribute listed with other attributes and I could also see it on my front end. I just could not see it in "Manage Customers" grid view and I would like to see it there mainly. Will your solution help me see it in admin section of Manage Customers?